# How to add subdomains to Azure web app?

Tags: azure, subdomain

I want to do .NET Core multitenancy app and every tenant has its own subdomain.

So, can I add **"subdomain"."appname".azurewebsites.net** for test purposes without buying new domain somehow? And how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Just get one of those free domains offered by many exotic holiday destination countries.

Comment: How that helps? Can you explain how to create the subdomain like app.mysite.azurewebsites.net?

Comment: You can't. Get a free domain (i.e. http://www.dot.tk) and point your subdomains (`kyle.broflovski.example.tk`) back to `yoursitename.azurewebsites.net`.